# base class extending and arrays

Tags: java

I want to have a base class and a couple of classes extending it.

Then I want to have an array that could be either of the two extending classes.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
class Base{  }
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}
```

then I want an array  that could be either A or B so I use Base in array declaration

```
Base[] it = Base[2];

it[0] = new A();
it[1] = new B();
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or if this allowed.

Thanks

Comment: Well did you try it? What happened?

Comment: That's the way to do it.  (Except, as amit points out, you're missing the `new` on the array creation.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword:

```
Base[] it = new Base[2];
```

Other then that - the approach is just fine. An array of type `Base[]` can hold objects of type `A` and `B`, since they are themselves extending the type `Base`.

**Example:**

```
static public class Base { 
    public void foo() { 
        System.out.println("I am base");
    }
}
static public class A extends Base { 
    @Override
    public void foo() { 
        System.out.println("I am A");
    }
}
static public class B extends Base { 
    @Override
    public void foo() { 
        System.out.println("I am B");
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base[] arr = new Base[2];
        arr[0] = new A();
        arr[1] = new B();
        arr[0].foo();
        arr[1].foo();
    }
```

Will result, as expected in printing:

```
I am A
I am B
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best thing to do here is to give it a try =) As to the question, yes it should work.